# How to read Memo type field from DBF file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro, foxpro

**I am unable to find the solution that how to read Memo type field from DBF file.**

As per my current RnD, I found out that the "Memo" data is stored in a separate file with the same name as the DBF file, but with a ".fpt" file extension. The "Memo" data file consists of a series of blocks, each of which contains a fixed number of bytes (typically 512 bytes), and each block is identified by a block number.

The "Memo" column in the DBF file contains a 10-byte pointer that identifies the block number of the first block of data for the corresponding record. If the data for a particular record exceeds the size of one block, additional blocks are allocated as needed and linked together using the pointers stored in the first block.

Moreover I used the source code provided [here](https://gist.github.com/sleimanzublidi/27acd30b5d4b452d5ec6)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace System.IO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class reads a dbf files
    /// </summary>
    public class DBFReader : IDisposable
    {
        private BinaryReader reader;
        private Encoding encoding;

        public DBFReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.encoding = encoding;
            this.reader = new BinaryReader(stream, encoding);

            ReadHeader();
        }

        public DBFReader(string filename, Encoding encoding)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename) == false)
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            this.encoding = encoding;
            var bs = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(filename));
            this.reader = new BinaryReader(bs, encoding);

            ReadHeader();
        }

        private void ReadHeader()
        {
            byte[] buffer = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DBFHeader)));

            // Marshall the header into a DBFHeader structure
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            this.header = (DBFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(DBFHeader));
            handle.Free();

            fields = new List<DBFFieldDescriptor>();
            while (reader.PeekChar() != 13)
            {
                buffer = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DBFFieldDescriptor)));
                handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                var fieldDescriptor = (DBFFieldDescriptor)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(DBFFieldDescriptor));
                if ((fieldDescriptor.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.System) != DBFFieldFlags.System )
                {
                    fields.Add(fieldDescriptor);
                }
                handle.Free();
            }

            byte headerTerminator = reader.ReadByte();
            byte[] backlink = reader.ReadBytes(263);
        }

        private void ReadRecords()
        {
            records = new List<Dictionary<DBFFieldDescriptor, object>>();

            // Skip back to the end of the header. 
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(header.HeaderLenght, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            for (int i = 0; i < header.NumberOfRecords; i++)
            {
                if (reader.PeekChar() == '*') // DELETED
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var record = new Dictionary<DBFFieldDescriptor, object>();
                var row = reader.ReadBytes(header.RecordLenght);

                foreach (var field in fields)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[field.FieldLength];
                    Array.Copy(row, field.Address, buffer, 0, field.FieldLength);
                    string text = (encoding.GetString(buffer) ?? String.Empty).Trim();

                    switch ((DBFFieldType)field.FieldType)
                    {
                        case DBFFieldType.Character:
                            record[field] = text;
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Currency:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = 0.0m;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = Convert.ToDecimal(text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Numeric:
                        case DBFFieldType.Float:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = 0.0f;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = Convert.ToSingle(text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Date:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = DateTime.MinValue;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.DateTime:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0) == 0)
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = DateTime.MinValue;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = JulianToDateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0));
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Double:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = 0.0;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = Convert.ToDouble(text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Integer:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);    
                            }
                            break;

                        case DBFFieldType.Logical:
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                            {
                                if ((field.Flags & DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues) == DBFFieldFlags.AllowNullValues)
                                {
                                    record[field] = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    record[field] = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                record[field] = (buffer[0] == 'Y' || buffer[0] == 'T');    
                            }
                            break;
                        
                        case DBFFieldType.Memo:
                        case DBFFieldType.General:
                        case DBFFieldType.Picture:
                        default:
                            record[field] = buffer;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                records.Add(record);
            }
        }

        public DataTable ReadToDataTable()
        {
            ReadRecords();

            var table = new DataTable();

            // Columns
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var colType = ToDbType(field.FieldType);
                var column = new DataColumn(field.FieldName, colType ?? typeof(String));
                table.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            // Rows
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (var column in record.Keys)
                {
                    row[column.FieldName] = record[column] ?? DBNull.Value;
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ReadToDictionary()
        {
            ReadRecords();
            return records.Select(record => record.ToDictionary(r => r.Key.FieldName, r => r.Value)).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> ReadToObject<T>()
            where T : new()
        {
            ReadRecords();

            var type = typeof(T);
            var list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                T item = new T();
                foreach (var pair in record.Select(s => new { Key = s.Key.FieldName, Value = s.Value }))
                {
                    var property = type.GetProperty(pair.Key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        if (property.PropertyType == pair.Value.GetType())
                        {
                            property.SetValue(item, pair.Value, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pair.Value != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                property.SetValue(item, System.Convert.ChangeType(pair.Value, property.PropertyType), null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.Add(item);
            }

            return list;
        }

        private DBFHeader header;
        private List<DBFFieldDescriptor> fields = new List<DBFFieldDescriptor>();

        private List<Dictionary<DBFFieldDescriptor, object>> records = new List<Dictionary<DBFFieldDescriptor,object>>();

        #region IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing == false) return;
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                reader = null;
            }
        }

        ~DBFReader()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        } 

        #endregion

         /// <summary>
        /// Convert a Julian Date as long to a .NET DateTime structure
        /// Implemented from pseudo code at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="julianDateAsLong">Julian Date to convert (days since 01/01/4713 BC)</param>
        /// <returns>DateTime</returns>
        private static DateTime JulianToDateTime(long julianDateAsLong)
         {
             if (julianDateAsLong == 0) return DateTime.MinValue;
            double p = Convert.ToDouble(julianDateAsLong);
            double s1 = p + 68569;
            double n = Math.Floor(4 * s1 / 146097);
            double s2 = s1 - Math.Floor(((146097 * n) + 3) / 4);
            double i = Math.Floor(4000 * (s2 + 1) / 1461001);
            double s3 = s2 - Math.Floor(1461 * i / 4) + 31;
            double q = Math.Floor(80 * s3 / 2447);
            double d = s3 - Math.Floor(2447 * q / 80);
            double s4 = Math.Floor(q / 11);
            double m = q + 2 - (12 * s4);
            double j = (100 * (n - 49)) + i + s4;
            return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(j), Convert.ToInt32(m), Convert.ToInt32(d));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the file header for a DBF. We do this special layout with everything
        /// packed so we can read straight from disk into the structure to populate it
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
        private struct DBFHeader
        {
            /// <summary>The version.</summary>
            public readonly DBFVersion Version;

            /// <summary>The update year.</summary>
            public readonly byte UpdateYear;

            /// <summary>The update month.</summary>
            public readonly byte UpdateMonth;

            /// <summary>The update day.</summary>
            public readonly byte UpdateDay;

            /// <summary>The number of records.</summary>
            public readonly int NumberOfRecords;

            /// <summary>The length of the header.</summary>
            public readonly short HeaderLenght;

            /// <summary>The length of the bytes records.</summary>
            public readonly short RecordLenght;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
            public readonly byte[] Reserved;

            /// <summary>Table Flags</summary>
            public readonly DBFTableFlags TableFlags;

            /// <summary>Code Page Mark</summary>
            public readonly byte CodePage;

            /// <summary>Reserved, contains 0x00</summary>
            public readonly short EndOfHeader;
        }

        public enum DBFVersion : byte
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            FoxBase = 0x02,
            FoxBaseDBase3NoMemo = 0x03,
            VisualFoxPro = 0x30,
            VisualFoxProWithAutoIncrement = 0x31,
            dBase4SQLTableNoMemo = 0x43,
            dBase4SQLSystemNoMemo = 0x63,
            FoxBaseDBase3WithMemo = 0x83,
            dBase4WithMemo = 0x8B,
            dBase4SQLTableWithMemo = 0xCB,
            FoxPro2WithMemo = 0xF5,
            FoxBASE = 0xFB
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DBFTableFlags : byte
        {
            None = 0x00,
            HasStructuralCDX = 0x01,
            HasMemoField = 0x02,
            IsDBC = 0x04
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the field descriptor structure. There will be one of these for each column in the table.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
        private struct DBFFieldDescriptor
        {
            /// <summary>The field name.</summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
            public readonly string FieldName;

            /// <summary>The field type.</summary>
            public readonly char FieldType;

            /// <summary>The field address.</summary>
            public readonly int Address;

            /// <summary>The field length in bytes.</summary>
            public readonly byte FieldLength;

            /// <summary>The field precision.</summary>
            public readonly byte DecimalCount;

            /// <summary>Field Flags</summary>
            public readonly DBFFieldFlags Flags;

            /// <summary>AutoIncrement next value</summary>
            public readonly int AutoIncrementNextValue;

            /// <summary>AutoIncrement step value</summary>
            public readonly byte AutoIncrementStepValue;

            /// <summary>Reserved</summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public readonly byte[] Reserved;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("{0} {1}", FieldName, FieldType);
            }
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DBFFieldFlags : byte
        {
            None = 0x00,
            System = 0x01,
            AllowNullValues = 0x02,
            Binary = 0x04,
            AutoIncrementing = 0x0C
        }

        public enum DBFFieldType : int
        {
            Character = 'C',
            Currency = 'Y',
            Numeric = 'N',
            Float = 'F',
            Date = 'D',
            DateTime = 'T',
            Double = 'B',
            Integer = 'I',
            Logical = 'L',
            Memo = 'M',
            General = 'G',
            Picture = 'P'
        }

        public static Type ToDbType(char type)
        {
            switch ((DBFFieldType)type)
            {
                case DBFFieldType.Float:
                    return typeof(float);

                case DBFFieldType.Integer:
                    return typeof(int);

                case DBFFieldType.Currency:
                    return typeof(decimal);

                case DBFFieldType.Character:
                case DBFFieldType.Memo:
                    return typeof(string);

                case DBFFieldType.Date:
                case DBFFieldType.DateTime:
                    return typeof(DateTime);

                case DBFFieldType.Logical:
                    return typeof(bool);

                case DBFFieldType.General:
                case DBFFieldType.Picture:
                    return typeof(byte[]);

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your question?
(Would be a mess as comment)

Your information about FPT file structure is not entirely correct and full details exist in the VFP help file.

Do you have to read it low level? If you have to, basically what you do is:

- Collect memo block numbers from the DBF itself (block numbers are stored in corresponding field in DBF),
- For a memo entry, go to block number in FPT (depends on block size)
- From the block header read the size and get the bytes that matches the stored size.

While doing that, always read as binary, because unlike C strings, VFP string values are not ASCIIZ values, they can even contain '\x0'.

If it is not a must to read that way then the easy way is to simply read it using VFPOLEDB OleDb driver. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    string cn = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data source=C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\SAMPLES\DATA;";
    string query = "select emp_id, first_name, last_name, notes  from Employee";

    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn).Fill(t);

    foreach (var row in t.AsEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{row["emp_id"]}, {row["first_name"]}, {row["last_name"]}, ({row["notes"]})");
    }
}
```

Note that VFPOLEDB driver is 32 bits, you would need to target x86 platform. There are 64 bits drivers from Sybase ADS as they say (have never used).

PS: Also search for Tom Brother's Linq To VFp, Linq To EF VFP drivers.
PS2: I quickly glanced the source code you provided, and beware that is for older VFP versions and is not really correct (ie: Assumes Memo is a string which is not correct - if you accept them string in C# you are likely going to lose many data).

Comment: @Fahad, hi. I think you didn't jus want to say hi :) I would edit the question to have a real question at least. That code is not completely correct as I already said.

Comment: @Fahad, oh sorry I wouldn't. It is not some code that one could write in 10-15 minutes. I wrote an older version years ago, but that was in VFP code (or even Foxpro 2.x). You can check the details of structures and missing datatypes in VFP help. If still you want me to do that, then need to talk about it in private.

Comment: Hi @Cetin Basoz
Yes. I am trying to find a solution for the 3 points you mentioned in your answer in c#

Comment: @Fahad, ok as I said all structure and data types are detailed in VFP help. You are not even telling why you need to do it in low level.